# Necesito guardar una variable para cada ejecución de un loop for JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un código para una simulación estadística en la cual existe un campo llamado `Probabilidad Acumulada`, la cual es una probabilidad que se obtiene sumando las probabilidades de cada suceso. Por ejemplo:

```
Probabilidad:
****************
Probabilidad: 
0.05
ProbabilidadAcumulada
0.05
****************
Probabilidad: 
0.15
ProbabilidadAcumulada
0.2
****************
Probabilidad: 
0.22
ProbabilidadAcumulada
0.42000002
****************
Probabilidad: 
0.38
ProbabilidadAcumulada
0.8
****************
Probabilidad: 
0.14
ProbabilidadAcumulada
0.94
****************
Probabilidad: 
0.06
ProbabilidadAcumulada
1.0
```

El código que uso es:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TareaSimulacion {

public class Resultado {
private double probabilidad;
private double probabilidadTotal;
                        }   


public static void main(String[] args)
{


       /**
 * Variables
 */

    float[] Probabilidad = new float[6];
    float total;
    int[] DemandaPorDia = new int[6];
    /**
 * Variables
 */

    Probabilidad[0]= (float) 0.05; Probabilidad[1]= (float) 0.15; Probabilidad[2]= (float) 0.22; Probabilidad[3]= (float) 0.38; Probabilidad[4]= (float) 0.14; Probabilidad[5]=(float) 0.06;


List<Resultado> resultados = new ArrayList<Resultado>();
Resultado resultado;

total=0;

for(int i=0; i<Probabilidad.length; i++)
{ 
    total += Probabilidad[i];
    System.out.println("La probabilidad es: "+Probabilidad[i]);
    System.out.println("Probabilidad Acumulada: "+total);

    resultado = new Resultado();
    resultado.setProbabilidad(Probabilidad[i]);
    resultado.setProbabilidadTotal(total);

    resultados.add(resultado);
}

    }

}
```

Ahora necesito poder guardar cada valor que tomo la probabilidad acumulada durante la corrida del bucle `for`. ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Comment: Cual es el código que has realizado? Te recomiendo leer: [__*"Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable"*__](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: El codigo que he realizado no va muy avanzado tan solo imprime por los momentos el vector con las probabilidades aqui lo pondre igualmente, como dije necesito saber como guardar el estado de una variable en cada uno de los recorridos del bucle for por separado, ya que necesitare usar las probabilidades acumuladas independientemente en un futuro

Answer (score 1):

En realidad ya tienes tu respuesta en tu mismo código, solo que no está organizado y puede que no entiendas algunos conceptos, por tanto, mi consejo es que uses los nombres de las variables de forma correcta (**Probabilad** debe ser: **probabiliades**, con minúscula y que sea significativo).

Aparte de ello, por simplicidad, debes tener un orden y tener un código más organizado, eso te ayuda a tí y a nosotros poder ayudarte.

Tu clase auxiliar **Resultado** debería estar fuera, a menos que exclusivamente quieras usar **clases internas** (es lo que tienes en tu código).

Un detalle, los números en float no son exactos, por tanto, te pueden dar valores con muchos decimales y no siempre iguales, así es Java con los float, por tanto, en mi ejemplo, en la clase **Resultado** modifico los getters para que obtengas valores de dos decimales y redondeados (Puedes poner los decimales que quieras).

En fin, te dejo **tu mismo código**, pero mejor organizado y con comentarios que te orientan de como va el código y con las mejoras que te he comentado.

```
package fips;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Clase a nivel de paquete, si se quiere, se puede
 * poner en otro fichero independiente para que la organización
 * sea mejor y más accesible si se desea que sea escalable.
 * @author ferpaxecosanxez.
 */
class Resultado {
    private double probabilidad;
    private double probabilidadTotal;

    // Getters y Setters.
    public void setProbabilidad(double probabilidad) {
        this.probabilidad = probabilidad;
    }
    public double getProbabilidad() {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(this.probabilidad);
        bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); 
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }
    public void setProbabilidadTotal(double probabilidadTotal) {
        this.probabilidadTotal = probabilidadTotal;
    }
    public double getProbabilidadTotal() {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(this.probabilidadTotal);
        bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); 
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }
}

/**
 * Clase principal, la cual contiene el método main y es la
 * única clase pública y debe de existir una única clase pública
 * en un fichero de clase.java, a menos que incluyas clases internas.
 * @author ferpaxecosanxez.
 */
public class MiClasePrincipal {
    /**
     * Método principal y único de ejecución.
     * @param args Argunmentos que en esta ocasión no lo usamos.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Variables.
        float[] probabilidades = new float[6];
        float total;
        // Valores de probabilidades.
        probabilidades[0] = (float) 0.05;
        probabilidades[1] = (float) 0.15;
        probabilidades[2] = (float) 0.22;
        probabilidades[3] = (float) 0.38;
        probabilidades[4] = (float) 0.14;
        probabilidades[5] = (float) 0.06;

        List<Resultado> resultados = new ArrayList<Resultado>();
        Resultado resultado;

        total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < probabilidades.length; i++) {
            total += probabilidades[i];
            System.out.println("La probabilidad es: " + probabilidades[i]);
            System.out.println("Probabilidad Acumulada: " + total);
            // Genero mi objeto Resultado y almaceno sus valores correspondientes.
            resultado = new Resultado();
            resultado.setProbabilidad(probabilidades[i]);
            resultado.setProbabilidadTotal(total);
            // Añadir el objeto Resultado con valores a la lista.
            resultados.add(resultado);
        }

        /* Los valores ya los tienes guardados, simplemente tienes que acceder a la
         * lista y usar sus get de sus atributos, por ejemplo, vamos a obtener la
         * cuarta(3) probabilidad almacenada
         */
        // Accedo a lista que ya tiene almacenado objetos de tipo Resultado.
        System.out.println("\n***********************************\n");
        Resultado resEjemplo = resultados.get(3);
        System.out.println("Cuarta probabilidad: "+resEjemplo.getProbabilidad());
        System.out.println("Total acumulado en ese instante: "+resEjemplo.getProbabilidadTotal());

        /* Si quiere obtener cada uno de los resultado, puedes usar un for-each simple,
         * en tal caso, tendríamos:
         */
        System.out.println("\n***********************************\n");
        System.out.println("Todas las probabilidades almacenadas:");
        for (Resultado res : resultados) {
            System.out.println("Probabilidad: "+res.getProbabilidad()+" | Total: "+res.getProbabilidadTotal());
        }
    }
}
```

El resultado de las pruebas realizadas y con los formatos adecuados es:

```
La probabilidad es: 0.05
Probabilidad Acumulada: 0.05
La probabilidad es: 0.15
Probabilidad Acumulada: 0.2
La probabilidad es: 0.22
Probabilidad Acumulada: 0.42000002
La probabilidad es: 0.38
Probabilidad Acumulada: 0.8
La probabilidad es: 0.14
Probabilidad Acumulada: 0.94
La probabilidad es: 0.06
Probabilidad Acumulada: 1.0

***********************************

Cuarta probabilidad: 0.38
Total acumulado en ese instante: 0.8

***********************************

Todas las probabilidades almacenadas:
Probabilidad: 0.05 | Total: 0.05
Probabilidad: 0.15 | Total: 0.2
Probabilidad: 0.22 | Total: 0.42
Probabilidad: 0.38 | Total: 0.8
Probabilidad: 0.14 | Total: 0.94
Probabilidad: 0.06 | Total: 1.0
```

Te repito, **tu mismo ya tenías la respuesta**, yo simplemente intento aclarartelo =D

Answer (score 0):

Intenta de la siguiente manera:

```
String sTotal="";
for(int i=0; i<Probabilidad.length; i++)
        { 
            sTotal = sTotal+Probabilidad[i]+";";
            total += Probabilidad[i];
            System.out.println("La probabilidad es: "+Probabilidad[i]);
            System.out.println("Probabilidad Acumulada: "+total);
        }
```

Una vez fuera del codigo tendremos tu variable **total** que supongo es int (necesitas ser mas descriptivo cuando formules preguntas aqui), y la variable **sTotal** que es un String con los valores que tenias en Arreglo Probabilidad[ ] sin embargo mas visible por ser una cadena de texto, si quieres extraer un valor especifico de este String puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
    String[] asTotal = sTotal.split(";");
```

Por ejemplo si tu **sTotal** al final del **for** consiguio el siguiente valor **"0.5;0.15;0.3;0.12;0.004"** el arreglo **asTotal** lo encontraremos tras el **split(";")** con los siguientes valores:

```
asTotal[0]="0.5";
asTotal[1]="0.15";
asTotal[2]="0.3";
asTotal[3]="0.12";
asTotal[4]="0.004";
```

Si esto no responde tu pregunta intenta reformularla.

Comment: Muchas gracias tambien voy a probar este metodo ya la conversion de string a int seria sencilla muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas guardar el resultado en cada operación te recomiendo que, o bien uses un nuevo vector para guardar las probabilidades en cada iteración, o que te crees una clase que tenga la probabilidad y la probabilidad acumulada para esa probabilidad. Te dejo un ejemplo, quedaría algo así:

Tendrías una clase para guardar los resultados...

```
public class Resultado {
    private double probabilidad;
    private double probabilidadTotal:

    //*** GETTERS Y SETTERS
}
```

En tu proceso guardarías en un array (por ejemplo) los resultados:

```
List<Resultado> resultados = new ArrayList<Resultado>();
Resultado resultado;

for(int i=0; i<Probabilidad.length; i++)
{ 
    total += Probabilidad[i];
    System.out.println("La probabilidad es: "+Probabilidad[i]);
    System.out.println("Probabilidad Acumulada: "+total);

    resultado = new Resultado();
    resultado.setProbabilidad(Probabilidad[i]);
    resultado.setProbabilidadTotal(total);

    resultados.add(resultado);
}
```

Al final del proceso, tendrás la colección `resultados` con objetos de tipo `Resultado` que tendrá la probabilidad y el total por cada iteración.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: falta resultados.add(resultado) en cada iteracion

Comment: Gracias Lithorell, se me había pasado. Es lo que tiene hacer las cosas "al vuelo" :D Gracias.

Comment: Yeah! muchas gracias eso era lo que necesitaba amigo justo lo que necesitaba!

Comment: Disculpa fernando ejecutando el codigo del ejemplo que me diste estoy teniendo el error 
Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context java
justo para esta linea 
                              "  resultado = new Resultado();"
He intentado declarar la variable resultado tanto fuera como dentro de mi funcion main y nada, 
Se declaro la variable como una variable de clase pero la estoy inicializando en un método estático.
Deberia bastar con declararla dentro de la funcion main pero el error persiste

Comment: Tendrías que poner el código completo para ver porque te puede fallar. De todas formas, el código que yo te he puesto es para que lo incluyeses dentro de tu método. Prueba primero en el método y luego lo sacas a la clase.

Comment: He actualizado el post para que veas el codigo detallado, muchas gracias por la atencion y disculpa la molestias

Comment: El problema es que cuando haces el `new` estas intentando instanciar una inner class. Para no complicarte la vida es mejor que la clase `Resultado` la saques a otro fichero.

Comment: Me dices que haga la clase en otro fichero y lo importe a mi fichero principal? tendria 1 documento solo para la clase Resultado y otro documento donde haga el llamado de la clase?

Comment: Hola JuanP, perdona que te haya contestado tan tarde. Efectivamente, sería tener en un fichero la clase `Resultado` y en otro lo demás. Tendrás que hacer un `import` y poco más.

Comment: Hola JuanP, al final resolviste este tema?